# Do I need a transit visa for a layover in Finland while I have a Danish residence permit?

Tags: schengen, denmark, finland

I have a residence and work permit for Denmark and since I'm flying there for the first time, my passport has not been stamped. Do I need a transit visa if I'm travelling through Finland (since it's in Schengen area), if that is going to be my first port of entry?

Also, does the same apply for a layover in any other Schengen country?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/38838/do-i-need-transit-visa-for-travelling-from-india-to-spain-via-brussels-with-span?rq=1) question answers the current one as well.

Give the following [here](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=celex:32013R0610):

> third-country nationals who do not fulfil all the conditions laid down in paragraph 1 but who hold a residence permit or a long-stay
>   visa shall be authorised to enter the territory of the other Member
>   States for transit purposes so that they may reach the territory of
>   the Member State which issued the residence permit or the long-stay
>   visa, unless their names are on the national list of alerts of the
>   Member State whose external borders they are seeking to cross and the
>   alert is accompanied by instructions to refuse entry or transit

I think this applies to my case here as well.

Comment: More likely, you do meet the conditions in paragraph 1, in which case it's not a problem in the least, and you could even stay in Finland for several days before making your way to Denmark.